# Did Marx imply that indigenous Mexicans were racially inferior?

Tags: economics

[image]

http://www.jstor.org/stable/41035216

> Marx classed the Indians of Mexico as "the last of men".

Is this an accurate representation of what Marx said?

Comment: Do you have access to reference 18?

Comment: What Marx "implied" is not on topic here, it's an opinion.

Comment: seems like this could be shipped to the History.SE